# JpaSpecification using Generics. Works with string, but issues with Date and joined fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to expand on this Baeldung tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications

But I want the Specification to be Generic and I wanted to allow the client to search by values of embedded objects. Everything works for String and some numbers, but not for ids and other more complicated objects like `Date`.

My Model: (assume a person can only have 1 pet)

```java
@Entity
public Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private ID id;
    private String name;
    private Date dateOfBirth
    private Integer age;
    private Pet pet;
    // Getter & Setters etc
}

@Entity
public Pet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private ID id;
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private Integer numOfLegs;
    // Getter & Setters etc
}
```

Person repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Person>{}
```

Search Criteria that will hold the key, operator and value that we can search by.

```java
public class EntitySearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private Object value;
    
    public EntitySearchCriteria(final String key, final String operation, final Object value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.operation = operation;
        this.value = value;
    }  
    // Getters and Setters etc
```

My Generic Specification class (this is really where the action is to build the predicates that are to be used). This also allows the client to set a SearchCriteria on a value of a joined table. e.g. "Pet.name=Muffins"

```java
public abstract class AbstractEntitySpecification<T, ID extends Serializable> implements Specification<T> {

    protected EntitySearchCriteria criteria;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(">")) {
            return criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
        } else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("<")) {
            return criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
        } else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(":")) {
            if (criteria.getKey().contains(".")) {
                String[] joinCriteriaArray = criteria.getKey().split("\\.");
                Class<?> joinedClass = root.get(joinCriteriaArray[0]).getClass();
                Join<T, ?> joinedRelationship = root.join(joinCriteriaArray[0]);
                return criteriaBuilder.equal(joinedRelationship.get(joinCriteriaArray[1]), criteria.getValue());
            }
            if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
                return criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), "%" + criteria.getValue() + "%");
            } else {
                return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any Entity that I want to allow this type of Querying then just needs to have a concrete implementation of the `AbstractEntitySpecification`

```java
public class PersonSpecification extends AbstractEntitySpecification<Person, Integer> {
    public PersonSpecification (final EntitySearchCriteria entitySearchCriteria) {
        this.criteria = entitySearchCriteria;
    }
}
```

These are the tests that I have run. Any search on a attribute of Person that is a String or Int (i.e. Person.name, Person.age) will work, but a search on dateOfBirth will not.
Any search on an attribute of the pet that is a string will work using the join, but searching on the id(Integer) will not, no matter if I pass the id as an Int, or a String. I have put the behaviour in a comment for each test.

```java
public class PersonSpecificationMediumTest extends AbstractMediumTest {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PetRepository petRepository;
    
    Person person1;
    Person person2;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Pet muffins = new Pet(1, "cat", "muffins", 4);
        Pet rex= new Pet(2, "dog", "rex", 4);
        petRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(muffins , rex));

        person1 = new Person();
        person1.setName("David");
        person1.setDateOfBirth(Date.parse("1979-03-01");
        person1.setPet(muffins);
        person1 = personRepository.saveAndFlush(person1);

        person2 = new Person();
        person2.setName("Mary");
        person2.setDateOfBirth(Date.parse("1982-03-01");
        person2.setPet(rex);
        person2 = personRepository.saveAndFlush(person2);
    }

    @Test //Works
    public void toPredicate_findByNameEquals_assertCorrectResult() {
        PersonSpecification spec
                = new PersonSpecification(new EntitySearchCriteria("name", ":", "David"));
        
        List<Person> results = personRepository.findAll(spec);
        
        Assert.assertEquals(person1, results.get(0));
    }

    @Test // Works
    public void toPredicate_findByPetNameEquals_assertCorrectResult() {
       PersonSpecification spec
                = new PersonSpecification(new EntitySearchCriteria("client.name", ":", "Rex"));
        
        List<Person> results = personRepository.findAll(spec);
        
         Assert.assertEquals(person2, results.get(0));
    }

    @Test // Return empty list. Cannot find the pet by Id.
    public void toPredicate_findByPetIdEquals_assertCorrectResult() {
         PersonSpecification spec
                = new PersonSpecification(new EntitySearchCriteria("pet.id", ":", 2));
        
         List<Person> results = personRepository.findAll(spec);
        
         Assert.assertEquals(person2, results.get(0));
    }

    @Test // org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)];
    public void toPredicate_findByPetIdAsStringEquals_assertCorrectResult() {
         PersonSpecification spec
                = new PersonSpecification(new EntitySearchCriteria("pet.id", ":", "2"));

         List<Person> results = personRepository.findAll(spec);

         Assert.assertEquals(person2, results.get(0));
    }

    @Test // Fails on org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2020-01-01] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
    public void toPredicate_findByDateOfBirthBetween_assertCorrectResult() {
        PersonSpecification spec1
                = new PersonSpecification(new EntitySearchCriteria("dateOfBirth", "<", "1990-01-01"));
        PersonSpecification spec2
                = new PersonSpecification(new EntitySearchCriteria("dateOfBirth", ">", "1970-01-01"));
        
        List<Person> results = personRepository.findAll(spec1.and(spec2));
        
        Assert.assertTrue(results.size() == 2);
    }
}
```

Any idea why Date is so problematic? I wanted use the date in the `greaterThanOrEqualTo` and `lessThanOrEqualTo`, but passing in criteria.getValue(Object) gives a compile error so it forces me to use a string representation of the object. But the error shown is `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2020-01-01] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]` which indicates to me that it cannot compare a String to a Date, which makes sense, but why stop me from passing the Date object?

Also, why is Id such an issue on the joined table? Why can it not find `id = 2`, I would have thought it would be straight forward, especially since I can search by the number of legs of the Pets successfully. It must have something to do with id being Serializable.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It will parse your string just fine and give you a `LocalDate`  object.

Comment: As I expected, that didn't work. I still get the following error `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2020-01-01] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2020-01-01] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]`

Comment: You probably need [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) for JSON serialization and deserialization to work. It’s not my home field, so please search for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JavaDoc for `Date.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String)). The essential part is already with the declaration:

> @Deprecated
> public static long parse(String s)

As it is clearly stated it returns a `long` value. To get a `Date` object you could use [`SimpleDateFormat` that inherits `DateFormat.parse(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)), like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d1 = sdf.parse("1979-03-01");
```

Comment: Ya, that's not my issue though, we have our own parsing tool that will return a Date object.